# Integrating Confluence and PostgreSQL via rest api's

Tags: postgresql, automation, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm new to confluence and would like to know that is there anyway I can connect part of an existing confluence page with another postgreSQL db by making API calls instead of creating any sockets from Confluence infrastructure. The below Image might help to understand what I want to achieve. I'm open to any or all options that can help me achieve this.

[image: Design]

Requirement:

- Have a confluence page updating the frontend with data from DB
- No/Minimal changes to the confluence Infra backend
- As I click on get data on the front end, It should fetch data from the DB and populate on the screen

I have tried googling all the similar solutions that I can find but I couldn't find any that suits the specific requirement that I have. I tried looking at Atlassian's page for connecting with DB and other db connecting guides from the below mentioned sources.

[Source 1 - Atlassian](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Setting-up-Postgresql-database-for-Confluence/qaq-p/759168)

[Source 2 - Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/database-setup-for-postgresql-173244522.html)

These two sources shows how to connect the DB using a JDBC connection to confluence and troubleshoot any issues arising out of it. Which I want to keep as the last resort to implement.

[Source 3 - Agix - uses JDBC](https://www.agix.com.au/preparing-postgresql-for-confluence-on-centos-7/)

This article also shows a way to connect Confluence server to db via jdbc, hosted on CentOs server.

[Source 4](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/connecting-jira-applications-to-postgresql-938846851.html)

This shows a way to connect Jira to DB again utilising the Jira Setup configuration.

Please note - I want to touch the Existing Confluence Infra as minimal as possible.

**Update:-** I have used the data source for the space to get the DB connected. Now the challenge is to get the Data from user and feed into the DB. Any leads, How can I do that? I'm using SQL macro to fetch the data from the DB but not sure how to feed user input from a form to the DB.

Comment: Could you please post the entire question and all related information, in just a single topic? Nobody wants to click and surf to other websites to understand your question.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Is this alright now ? Unfortunately I can't embed images into the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to use PostgreSQL as core data DB for Confluence then you just need to follow those guides you specified links to as Confluence supports most SQL databases. But if you mean to get data from some other PostgreSQL DB just as container of some data or system - it seems to be better option to configure separate DB for Confluence (as it is rather big) and use Java API/ REST API to integrate the systems.

Comment: i have used the Database source now to resolve the issue. But now I'm stuck as I want to feed the data from Confluence page (boxes) into the DB. Any leads how that can be achieved?